# Text box value format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a textbox. It can accepts numeric as well as alphabets. I need to format the value of text box at run time such that whenever a Numberic/Alphabet is pressed and the previous is of other category(Alphabet/Numeric), it should automatically insert a `-` sign.

For example: `AB108B8` should be formatted as `AB-108-B-8`

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for such behavior? Following code try to support the situation when user is typing in continuously without changing the cursor position with arrow keys. You can take an idea from this piece of code and modify it according to your need.

```js
var isOppositeChar = false;
$('#field').keypress(function(event ) {
    var $field = $(this);

    // this is the value before the keypress
    var beforeVal = $field.val();
    var newVal = beforeVal;
 
    if(beforeVal.length > 0 )
    {
     
      var chkResult = checkLastChar(beforeVal,event.key);
      if(chkResult)
        newVal +=event.key;
      else
        newVal += "-"+event.key;
      event.preventDefault();
      $field.val(newVal);
    } 

  
});

function checkLastChar(fieldVal,newChar){
  var lastChar = fieldVal[fieldVal.length - 1];
  var lastCharIsAlphabate = false;
  var newCharIsAlphabate = false;
  
  if(isNaN(lastChar))
    lastCharIsAlphabate = true;
  
  if(isNaN(newChar))
    newCharIsAlphabate = true;
  
  if(lastCharIsAlphabate == newCharIsAlphabate)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=field />
```

**Note**: Above code doesn't take care for keyboard arrow key navigation and insertion of char at any particular place within existing typed-in text. Also it doesn't support copy paste process.